# Cannot Get DBMail to Work. Worked in the Past

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent, dbmail

SQL Server 2005 DBMail.
I had all of this working, but then it just stopped.  I tried starting over from scratch to no avail

The surface area configuration tool has been used to make sure the procs in msdb are active.

I've tried stopping and starting the mail service with sysmail_stop_sp and sysmail_start_sp.

I made sure that the Mail Profile is enabled in the ALert System section of SQL Server Agent. I did change the profile being used some time ago and have NOT cycled the server up and down - it would be a big deal to do this.

I've tried stopping and starting SQL Server agent.

I've confirmed that the user belongs to the msdb database and has the role DatabaseMailUserRole.

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb' 
1

dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;
STARTED

sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'Mail'
mail    258 NOTIFIED    2011-08-19 16:51:34.500 2011-08-19 16:51:34.500
```

The state used to be `RECEIVES_OCCURRING` when it was working.

All email queues up with a sent_status of Unsent.

I've triple checked my email credentials and they're all good.  I've tried ports 25 and 2525, both of which are accepted by my provider.

I've verified that the credentials are good by setting them up in another mail client ans successfully using them to send mail.

Am at wit's end.  Anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: what about smtpsend.exe from the database server? http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=smtpsend And you have a 0% success rate and no upvotes for your questions so far...

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem before, it’s the dbmail setup within sql that’s corrupted or as Microsoft told me "stalled" are you sending HTML over the dbmail from say a job within sql using cast?

If so check the job and make sure there isn’t a problem inside first but what i did was delete the dbmail profile and then just re made it and then it just decided to start working again.

Have you also looked with the administrate tools as usually it will post an application error on why it failed (inside control panel)

Let me know if the deletion of the profile worked and i can maybe take you through a couple of things i was told to try first.

Comment: also try right clikcing on Database Mail inside management and press send test email and see if that works first as if that DOES send an email we know its the content or the query itself if it doesnt most likely the service itself.